# Is there a website to ask for people to make script for you?

Tags: website, script

I don't have enought knowledge to make something that would do what I want. I there somewhere I could ask someone else to do the job? I think I already stumble upon something like this, each post was like a contest to the programmer.

Comment: Voted to close: "Questions on Super User are expected to generally relate to computer software or computer hardware in some way, within the scope defined in the faq."

Answer (score 2):

> I think I already stumble upon
>   something like this, each post was
>   like a contest to the programmer.

Sounds like RentACoder.

> Need custom software? Receive bids from
>   our pool of 290,043 registered workers.

http://www.rentacoder.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you have some knowledge, with basic requirements, you could always try [StackOverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com), SuperUser's big brother site, so-to-speak.  There's a strong community of developers there that are always willing to help out as long as you ask the question clearly, it's of interest to a developer, and it's not for school (they are not there to do homework for students).